# How to expediate MySQL CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE?

Tags: mysql, create-table

I am trying to tune my long running queries to preform better in MySQL. one of the things that I have done was to use `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE (KEY(account_id)).....` instead of using complex LEFT JOIN to many sub queries.

But I am noticing that creating temporary table is slow "it could also be creating the key on that table."

Is there a configuration in MySQL so that  `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE (KEY(account_id)).....` is faster?

I have change the following variables

```
tmp_table_size=32M
max_heap_table_size=32M
key_buffer_size=8M
```

TO

```
tmp_table_size=64M
max_heap_table_size=64M
key_buffer_size=32M
```

Comment: Are you creating the table with `create temporary table your_table select ...`?

Comment: Use the engine `MEMORY`, which you can specify at the end of the `create table`.

Comment: @Barranka yes CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tbl (KEY(account_id)) AS SELECT account_id FROM ......

Comment: @Mike Maybe if you create the index (or indexes) *after* the creation of the table things may speed up a bit: `create temporary table tbl select acount_id from ...; alter table tbl add primary key(account_id);`